# ViewDidAppear on a UINavigationController not getting called when navigating back

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I have a `UITabBarController` that hosts 5 `UINavigationControllers` (let's call them N1 - N5).  Each of the `UINavigationControllers` has UI elements that cause a UITableViewController to be pushed onto the navigation stack (I use `MonoTouch.Dialog` `DialogViewController` to implement these `UITableViewControllers`). Let's call those T1 - T5.

When I navigate between the tabs, the `ViewDidAppear` method gets called on each of N1 - N5 as expected.  But when I touch a UI element on, say, N1, that causes T1 to get pushed onto the nav stack, and then try to go back using the back button, N1's `ViewDidAppear` method doesn't get called.

The funny thing is that if I "tab over" to a different tab (say N2) and then "tab back" to N1, the `ViewDidAppear` will be called as normal.  And even if I have T1 pushed onto the nav stack, if I do the same tabbing around, N1's `ViewDidAppear` will still be called.

The `MonoTouch` code for N1 looks like this:

```
public class CalendarPage : UINavigationController
{
    private DialogViewController dvc;

    public override void ViewDidAppear (bool animated)
    {           
        // initialize controls
        var now = DateTime.Today;
        var root = new RootElement("Calendar")
        {
            from it in App.ViewModel.Items
                where it.Due != null && it.Due >= now
                orderby it.Due ascending
                group it by it.Due into g
                select new Section (((DateTime) g.Key).ToString("d")) 
                {
                    from hs in g
                        select (Element) new StringElement (((DateTime) hs.Due).ToString("d"),
                            delegate 
                            {
                                ItemPage itemPage = new ItemPage(this, hs);
                                itemPage.PushViewController();
                            })
                        { 
                            Value = hs.Name
                        }                                                    
                }
        };

        if (dvc == null)
        {
            // create and push the dialog view onto the nav stack
            dvc = new DialogViewController(UITableViewStyle.Plain, root);
            dvc.NavigationItem.HidesBackButton = true;  
            dvc.Title = NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString ("Calendar", "Calendar");
            this.PushViewController(dvc, false);
        }
        else
        {
            // refresh the dialog view controller with the new root
            var oldroot = dvc.Root;
            dvc.Root = root;
            oldroot.Dispose();
            dvc.ReloadData();
        }
        base.ViewDidAppear (animated);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was going on.  When the back button is pressed on the inner `DialogViewController` (created in ItemPage), the outer `DialogViewController` ("T1" above) is now the first responder, NOT the `UINavigationController` ("N1").  My confusion stemmed from the fact that I turned the back button off on that outer `DialogViewController` so I was assuming I had popped out all the way to the `UINavigationController` (N1), whereas I was still in a `DialogViewController` (T1).

I implemented the desired behavior (refreshing the contents of "T1") by creating a `ViewDissapearing` event on the inner `DialogViewController` (ItemPage in this case) and checking whether I am popping out - and if so, invoking the parent controller's `ViewDidAppear` method.

```
        actionsViewController.ViewDissapearing += (sender, e) => 
        {
            if (actionsViewController.IsMovingFromParentViewController)
                controller.ViewDidAppear(false);
        };
```

Note the funny thing about this code is that the property that actually works is `IsMovingFromParentViewController`, NOT `IsMovingToParentViewController` (which is intuitively what you'd think would be set when you're navigating back).  I imagine this may be a bug in MT.Dialog, but something that can't be fixed for back-compact reasons.

I hope this ends up helping someone...